# How to compare the two input fields values inside formarray in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Html Code:(In this FormArray, I have shipment_order_units, shipping_order_units => suppose shipment have 10, shipping should have less than or equal to 10.. user should not be able to enter more than 10.. I need to validate like this..)

```
      <div formArrayName="orderNumList" *ngFor="let item of orderNumArray.controls;let i=index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i" class="add-div">
                      <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Shipping order 
                           product quantity" formControlName="shipment_product_order_qty" readonly>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Shipment Order Units"
                            formControlName="shipment_order_units" readonly>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput type="number" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" placeholder="Shipping Order Units"
                            formControlName="shipping_order_units" required>
                   </mat-form-field>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Component.ts:(In this FormArray, I have shipment_order_units, shipping_order_units => suppose shipment have 10, shipping should have less than or equal to 10.. user should not be able to enter more than 10.. I need to validate like this..)

```
    ngOninit(){
      this.packForm = new FormGroup ({
            'orderNumList':new FormArray([])
        });
         this.orderNumArray = this.packForm.get('orderNumList') as FormArray;
        this.addItem();
      }
      addItem(){
    this.orderNumArray.push(this.createItem());
  }
  createItem():FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
       shipment_product_order_qty:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
       shipment_order_units:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
      shipping_order_units:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
     });
  }
```

Comment: Does this is what you want?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-shnzkn Setting the value of ```shipment_order_units``` as a max value to ```shipping_order_units``` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for(let i = 0; i<this.orderNumArray.length; i++){ 
     this.orderNumArray.at(i).get('shipping_order_units')
       .setValidators(Validators.compose( [Validators.required, 
         Validators.max(this.orderNumArray.at(i).get('shipment_order_units').value)])); 
         this.packForm.updateValueAndValidity(); 
      }
```

Comment: Whenever you add a solution you need to explain with relevant details.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to implement the [**Validators.max()**](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#max) method and need to get the value of `shipment_order_units` and set it as max value for `shipping_order_units`.

With the use [**setValidators()**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators) method you can make the validation like,

```
this.formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units.setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.max(this.formGroup.controls.shipment_order_units.value)]));
```

So the **component.html** file would like,

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span class="fill-remaining-space">My Reactive Form with Material</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="container" *ngIf="!post; else forminfo" novalidate> 
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)" class="form">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Shipping order product quantity" formControlName="shipment_product_order_qty" readonly>
      </mat-form-field>

        <span *ngIf="formGroup.controls.shipment_product_order_qty && formGroup.controls.shipment_product_order_qty.errors">
        <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.shipment_product_order_qty.errors.required">
          Shipping Product Order quantity is required
        </mat-error>
        </span>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Shipment Order Units"
            formControlName="shipment_order_units" readonly>
      </mat-form-field>


      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput type="number" pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" max="5" placeholder="Shipping Order Units"
              formControlName="shipping_order_units" >
      </mat-form-field>

    <span *ngIf="formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units && formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units.errors">
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units.errors.max"> Shipping Order Units value should be less than or equal to {{formGroup.controls.shipment_order_units.value}} </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units.errors.required">
        Shipping Order Units is required
      </mat-error>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

And **component.ts** file would be,

```
export class AppComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';
  post: any = '';

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'shipment_product_order_qty': [, [Validators.required]],
      'shipment_order_units': [10, Validators.required],
      'shipping_order_units': ['', [Validators.min(0)]]
    });

    this.formGroup.controls.shipping_order_units.setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.max(this.formGroup.controls.shipment_order_units.value)]));      

  this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').valueChanges
  .subscribe(val => {
    if(!this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').errors){
    this.formGroup.get('shipment_product_order_qty').setValue(this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').value * 10);
    } else {
      this.formGroup.get('shipment_product_order_qty').setValue('');
    }
  }
);
}

}
```

Here to set the product quantity as mutiple of `10` to the `shipping_order_units`, you can check for [valueChanges](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#displaying-a-form-control-value) and can subscribe and set the value of quantity if only `shipping_order_units` is valid like,

```
  this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').valueChanges
  .subscribe(val => {
    if(!this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').errors){
    this.formGroup.get('shipment_product_order_qty').setValue(this.formGroup.get('shipping_order_units').value * 10);
    } else {
      this.formGroup.get('shipment_product_order_qty').setValue('');
    }
  }
```

> [**Working Stackblitz example here..**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-uojk48)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the value from the field and compare it where you handle the click event:

```
const a = this.form.controls['a'].value
const b = this.form.controls['b'].value

if(a >= b) { }
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this method.. its not working..and your answer is not enough to solve my question..

Comment: @Rekha, Can you look at the stackblitz which I have provided above in comments and let me know whether that is what you want..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, Thank you so much,, you solution is perfectly working.. I need one more help.. In that shipment qty field should change based on shipping order units.. For example, shipping unit is 5, so shipment qty should change 50.. it should be multiplied by 10..can you do this?

Comment: @Rekha, I have added as an answer with the feature of updating the quantity based on the condition you said..

Comment: I have tried to implement this logic in my code.. but i got "Cannot read property 'setValidators' of undefined"  error..

Comment: for(let i = 0; i<this.orderNumArray.length; i++){
            this.orderNumArray.at(i).get('shipping_order_units').setValidators(Validators.compose(
              [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.orderNumArray.at(i).get('shipment_order_units').value)]));      
           this.packForm.updateValueAndValidity();
             
            }

Comment: @Rekha, Please do comment below my answer.. If you do it here unless you mention name I won't get notification.. Okay what is the issue now?? Please comment your issue below my solution..

Comment: @Rekha, The solution which I gave is based on the inputs given by you and you have not provided any stackblitz.. I have made it and explained how actually you need to do.. You only know how your real application code would be and need to implement the same.. If my solution solves your issue feel free to accept..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan  yes, you are right.. Now I understood what you are saying.. Thank you so much for you help to solve this question..

Comment: @Rekha, Glad to help you.. Also in future try to comment under respective solution and not on other solution like this.. Also please consider deleting your answer if you cannot explain in detail of the solution.. Because consider posting the solution only you have relevant details.. Happy coding ..